# Help with running Siege Of Avalon

Tags: technical-issues, backwards-compatibility, siege-of-avalon

I'm trying to play Siege of Avalon. I have Windows XP. I have tried the program compatibility wizard with no luck. I tried running it in Windows 98 with and without 256 color and the same for disabling visual themes. I have tried every combination.

There are two different things going on.

The first is when I try to start the game, it goes to just a black screen, and when I try to get back to my desktop or exit the game it freeze's up. The only way I can get out of the game, other than manually restarted my computer, is to eject the game disk, then put it back in, then this box comes up saying that the program is not responding, then I push end now. After it ends the game restarts from me putting the game disk back in.

Now that's a lot of trouble just to play a game. But I would play like that if it wasn't for the color problem. Everything but the people comes out purple and green. Please help me if you can, I would love to play this game thank you.

[image: Siege Of Avalon]

Comment: Try disabling the cache

Comment: Thank's I tried,but it didn't work.any other ideas.Really would like to play this game.The copy I have is from global star the one with 6 chapters.I am not very computer smart,but it is called siege of avalon antholgy.Not sure what that means.Also correct me if I am wrong,but this game is not a dos game right.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this game is in need of a patch. The latest one I could find is here:

http://www.playerattack.com/file/12746/Siege-of-Avalon-Patch-1.4-Unofficial/

The above link has some install instructions and seems to contain all the previous patches.

I wouldn't trust the later version patches from softpedia.com.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to disable hardware acceleration for this to work.

And if I remember correctly, you can only do this with direct x dev tools or dev kit (whatever it's called).

And I believe this is only possible up until Windows 7, but search for "disable hardware acceleration" might also help.